# To check if print command was sent to the printer in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I use

```
 printDialog.PrintVisual(document, "doc");
```

to open a print dialog for the default printer when user clicks on a print button in my WPF application. The problem is that I want to know whether user clicked on the "Print" button in the external print dialog or "Cancel" button. I want to display respective messages based on user actions.

Is there a callback function implemented in the WPF printing process?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ShowDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.printdialog.showdialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method on the PrintDialog class returns a boolean indicating if the print button was pressed or not.

```
PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog(); 
if (dialog.ShowDialog()) 
  printDialog.PrintVisual(document, "doc");
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. Create a PrintDialog**

The following code creates a PrintDialog in WPF code.

```
// Create a PrintDialog
PrintDialog printDlg = new PrintDialog();
```

**2. Create a FlowDocument**

The FlowDocument object is used to create a FlowDocument. It has items such as a paragraph, run, line, image and so on. The following code snippet creates a FlowDocument and adds a line of text to the document.

```
// Create a FlowDocument dynamically.
FlowDocument doc = new FlowDocument(new Paragraph(new Run("Some text goes here")));
doc.Name = "FlowDoc";
```

**3. Create an IDocumentPaginatorSource**

The third step is to create an IDocumentPaginatorSource object from a FlowDocument that is pretty simple as listed here. You directly convert a FlowDocument to an IDocumentPaginatorSource.

```
// Create IDocumentPaginatorSource from FlowDocument
IDocumentPaginatorSource idpSource = doc;
```

**4. Call PrintDialog.PrintDocument method**

The last step is to call PrintDialog.PrintDocument method to call the print dialog that will allow you to select a printer and send document to the printer to print it. The PrintDocument method of PrintDialog takes a DocumentPaginator object that you can get from IDocumentPaginatorSource.DocumentPaginator property as listed in the following code:

```
// Call PrintDocument method to send document to printer
printDlg.PrintDocument(idpSource.DocumentPaginator, "Hello WPF Printing.");
```

[c-sharpcorner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/printing-in-wpf/)